# Why on enums is .allCases.forEach not a loop (continue and break don't work)?

Tags: swift, loops, enums

I want to iterate through all values in an enum but given certain conditions I want to give up and move to the next value.  Any attempt at a `break` or `continue` statement and the compiler says that '.allCases.forEach' is not a loop as in 'func test1'.

The best workaround I've come up with is `func test2` but it seems "non-swifty" and I could just have a bunch of nested `if` blocks that seem extra. So what is `.allCases.forEach` if not a loop and more importantly, is there a different/better way to iterate through the `enum`?

Updated: added func 'processFoolPower' with solution 1 as a small example of the goal. Think large chess board.

```swift
enum directions: Int, CaseIterable {
    case up = 0, upRight, right, downRight, down, downLeft, left, upLeft, invalid
}

func test1() {
    print("forEach: ")
    moveDirections.allCases.forEach {
        if $0 == .up { () }         // I want to { continue } here to next direction
        if $0.rawValue == 4 { () }  // or { continue } here to next direction
        testPrint(test: $0)
    }
}

func test2() {
    print("for : ")
    for direction in 0..<moveDirections.allCases.count {
        if moveDirections(rawValue: direction) == .up { continue }
        if direction == 4 { continue }
        testPrint(test: moveDirections(rawValue: direction).self!)
    }
}

func testPrint(test: moveDirections) {
    print(test.self)
}


    mutating func processFoolPower(foolPiece: gamePiece, owner: Bool) {

        var testPiece: gamePiece = MockData.blankPiece
        
        for direction in moveDirections.allCases {
            let testSquare = foolPiece.location! + SquareShift(direction)
            if testSquare < 0 || testSquare > 143  { continue }                                     // test for off top/bottom of board
            switch direction {
            case .down, .up, .left, .right:
                if isStraight(from: foolPiece.location!, to: testSquare) == .invalid { continue }   // test for off sides of board
            case .upLeft, .downLeft, .upRight, .downRight: ()
                if isDiagonal(from: foolPiece.location!, to: testSquare) == .invalid { continue }   // test for off sides of board
            case .invalid: ()
            }
            testPiece = pieces.first(where: { $0.location == testSquare }) ?? MockData.blankPiece
            if testPiece.status != .dead { executeKill(pieceId: testPiece.id, explanation: .blownUp) }
        }
        executeKill(pieceId: foolPiece.id, explanation: .exploded)
    }
```

Comment: This really has nothing to do with enums, or `allCases`. `forEach` is just a method that takes a closure. Closures can't use `continue` and `break`. It would be theoretically possible to build that as a language feature (e.g. Ruby does it), but it leads to some gotchas/complexity (e.g. like Ruby has :D ). Your intuition to replace this with a `for` loop is correct. As Paul shows, you can just iterate over the directions themselves, withotu all of this complexity with ranges, counts, and raw values.

Comment: In your real code, what you be doing with this loop, instead of calling this `testPrint` function? I suspect that what you're ultimately looking for is `filter` or `compactMap`.

Comment: In the real code it's a game and I'm checking what is next to this piece in all directions and if they are affected by this piece, the piece is at the edge of the board, blocked by another piece etc. then I ignore and go to the next direction.

Comment: Could you show a simplified code example of that? I think `contains(where:)` might also be of help here, but it depends on the details

Comment: I apologize if editing the original was not the right way but couldn't see how to post code except as an answer.  I included one of the most basic functions I have.  I tried various uses of contains where with limited success like this. I'm sure this is overly complicated too. I'm still struggling with some of the basic Swift concepts. '    func pieceAtSquare(_ square: Int) -> gamePiece? {
        if pieces.contains(where: ({ $0.location == square })) {
            return pieces.first(where: ({ $0.location == square }))
        } else { return nil }
    }

Comment: Alas, there's no way to make large code blocks in comments. A really annoying reistriction. I've updated my answer to address your new example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/foreach(_:)) is an array function that iterates over the elements, invoking a closure, like `map`; It isn't a Swift loop construct, so you can't use `break` or `continue`.

Your second attempt is closer to what you need, but unnecessarily complicated. There is no need for an index or raw values.

You can use a `for in` loop with a collection's elements directly:

```
enum directions: Int, CaseIterable {
    case up = 0, upRight, right, downRight, down, downLeft, left, upLeft, invalid
}

for direction in directions.allCases { 
    if direction == .up { 
        continue 
    }
    print(direction)
}
```

Comment: Advanced syntax: `for direction in directions.allCases where direction != .up`

Answer (score 3):

I think what you might ultimately be looking for is [`Array.filter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/defaultindices/filter(_:)):

```swift
directions.allCases
    .filter { ![.up, .down].contains($0) }
    .forEach { print($0) }
```

For checking against two specific cases like this, I could have done `$0 != .up && $0 != .down`, but I opted to check it against an array instead with [`Array.contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/contains(_:)). I find it a bit tidier, and makes it easier to add or remove cases easier.

---

In response to your update, here's a rough idea how you can write your `processFoolPower(foolPiece:owner:)` function in a way that doesn't even need `continue`:

```swift
mutating func processFoolPower(foolPiece: gamePiece, owner: Bool) {
    let testSquares = moveDirections.allCases
        .filterMap { direction in
            let testSquare = foolPiece.location! + SquareShift(direction)
            if !(0...143).contains(testSquare) { return nil }

            switch direction {
            case .down, .up, .left, .right:
                if isStraight(from: foolPiece.location!, to: testSquare) == .invalid { return nil }   // test for off sides of board
            case .upLeft, .downLeft, .upRight, .downRight: ()
                if isDiagonal(from: foolPiece.location!, to: testSquare) == .invalid { return nil }   // test for off sides of board
            case .invalid: return nil
            }

            return testSquare
        }

    for testSquare in testSquares {
        if let target = pieces.first(where: { $0.location == testSquare }), target.status != .dead {
            executeKill(pieceId: testPiece.id, explanation: .blownUp)
        }   
    }

    executeKill(pieceId: foolPiece.id, explanation: .exploded)
}
```

In this case, this style doesn't make that much of an improvement, but where it can come in really handy is if you want to break these pieces apart to test independently. E.g. the move filtering part can easily be extracted, to see if you test the correct squares for each direction.

---

In your comment, you mentioned this snipet:

```swift
func pieceAtSquare(_ square: Int) -> gamePiece? {
    if pieces.contains(where: ({ $0.location == square })) {
       return pieces.first(where: ({ $0.location == square }))
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

If you take a step back, and have a look at the general intent here, you'll notice something interesting:

1. If `pieces` contains a piece at the given location, then you'll search the `pieces` for the given location, and return the first hit, if any. If not, you return `nil`.
2. Otherwise you return `nil`.

Notice here that you're searching twice. If the first `contains(where:)` check passes, then the `first(where:)` is sure to succeed. You don't need the `contains` check at all, so this just boiled down to:

```swift
func pieceAtSquare(_ square: Int) -> gamePiece? {
    pieces.first { $0.location == square }
}
```

(I just used trailing closure syntax to remove some excess parens, and used an implicit `return`, since this is now just a 1-liner.

Comment: Thanks for this too.  The first answer was perfect because my actual 'if ... { continue }' tests are much more involved that the sample code above but your solution will help me elsewhere and is another very clean approach I did not find in all of my searching.

Comment: @DouglasCurran That’s great to hear, happy I could help. The complexity of the `if` statements predicate doesn’t matter much: if the fundamental operation is to filter some elements from being used in some way, then this approach should work. If you have case where it doesn’t fit, you should share the details, and people might be able to suggest better alternatives

Comment: @Alexander can you point the `include` method documentation?

Comment: @LeoDabus No, because it doesn't exist :D I've been doing too much Ruby in my day job haha.

Comment:        